# Wrap state in MATLAB (2015a)

Tags: matlab, simulink

In this documentation for Integrator and Integrator limited  (http://in.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/integrator.html?searchHighlight=wrap%20state) showing Wrap state option but in MATLAB 2015a this is not showing. Is this the new update  in MATLAB 2016a? And what advantage it has provided in Integrator block?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a new feature introduced in R2015b, see the [release notes](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/release-notes.html).

> The [Integrator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/simulink/slref/integrator.html) block has been enhanced to support wrapped states
>   when modeling rotary, cyclic, or periodic state trajectories. This
>   support for wrapping states provides these advantages.
>
> - It eliminates simulation instability when your model approaches large angles and large state values.
> - It reduces the number of solver resets during simulation and eliminates the need for zero-crossing detection, improving simulation
>     time.
> - It eliminates large angle values, speeding up computation of trigonometric functions on angular states.
> - It improves solver accuracy and performance and enables unlimited simulation time.